# abstract clases when handling a job in Laravel

Tags: php, oop, laravel, message-queue

I'm trying to reuse a Job code for handling two different tasks with same methods (MyClass1 and MyClass2). I've write an abstract class for passing it to the Job handler, however I get the message 'is not instantiable'.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
    abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {
            abstract public function doSomething();
    }

    class MyClass1 extends MyAbstractClass
    {
            public function doSomething(){
                    // do some staff
            }
    }

    class MyClass2 extends MyAbstractClass
    {
            public function doSomething(){
                    // do some staff
            }
    }

    class MyJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
    {
            use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

            public function __construct()
            {

            }

            public function handle(MyAbstractClass $myObj)
            {
                    $myObj->doSomething();
                    // it executes the method doSomething of MyClass1 or  MyClass2 depending on the enqueued Job
            }
    }
```

Any solution? If not, I will do two Jobs, one for each class... what do you think?

Thank you

Comment: You must implement an interface.. and use that interface for type casting..

Comment: What is the exact error you get and where exactly do you get it? I think it is a the place where the handler classes are created, but it is not shown in the code above.

Comment: I do ```dispatch(new MyJob())``` and then the job is enqueued. Then I run the command ```php artisan queue:listen``` and the job is handled getting the message: [Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]  
  Target [MyAbstractClass] is not instantiable.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from service contrainer, which doesn't know what object inject